# Understanding Equivalence of Categories

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

An equivalence of two categories $\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}$ consists of a pair of functors $F:\mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$, $G:\mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ and natural isomorphisms $FG \rightarrow \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}}$, $GF \rightarrow \mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{C}}$.

Now then, what is a natural isomorphism? Let $S,T:\mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}$ be equi(?)variant functors. A natural isomorphism $\tau:S \rightarrow T$ is a family of morphisms in $\mathcal{B}$, $\tau = (\tau_A:S(A)\rightarrow T(A))_{A\in \mathrm{ob}(\mathcal{A})}$, such that for any $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A,A')$ we have $\tau_{A'}S(f)=T(f)\tau_A$, and each $\tau_A$ is an isomorphism. (This is from Rotman's Introduction to Hom. Algebra.)

Finally, the actual question: What does this entail in the context of equivalence of categories (first paragraph)? My guess is the following: A natural isomorphism $\varepsilon:FG \rightarrow \mathrm{id}_\mathcal{D}$ means a family of morphisms in $\mathcal{D}$, $\varepsilon=(\varepsilon:FG(D) \rightarrow \mathrm{id}_\mathcal{D}(D)=D)_{D \in \mathrm{ob}(\mathcal{D})}$ such that for any $f \in \mathrm{Hom}_\mathcal{D}(D,D')$, $\varepsilon_{D'}FG(f)=f \varepsilon_D$ and each $\varepsilon_D$ is an isomorphism. And analogously for the other pair of functors.

My confusion lies in what functors are "compared" in the equivalence.

Comment: In order to get a fealing for this notion, work out examples in detail! You can find many basic examples on Wikipedia or at the nlab.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg nlab? :)

Comment: @ErikVesterlund [nlab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage), a kind of math encyclopaedia with a (higher) categorical point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works pretty much like other isomorphisms in mathematics. For instance, if I want to show that two topological spaces are isomorphic, I want maps $f:X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow X$ such that $g \circ f = id_X$ and $f \circ g = id_Y$. Now, it would make sense to say that an equivalence of categories is a pair of functors $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ and $G: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ such that $G \circ F = id_\mathcal{C}$ and $G \circ F = id_\mathcal{D}$, where you compose functors as expected and $id$ is the identity functor.

But the problem is that in practice, wanting the two functors to be *exactly equal* is asking far, far too much, because in category theory, we usually don't care if two objects are *exactly equal*. If they're isomorphic, that's almost always good enough. So we relax the equality above to natural isomorphism.

So for each object of $D$, we have that $FG(D)$ is *isomorphic* to $D$ via some isomorphism $\epsilon_D:FG(D) \rightarrow D$, and that all these isomorphisms are compatible with arrows in $D$, in the sense that if we go from $D$ to $D'$ via $f:D \rightarrow D'$, then $f \circ \epsilon_D = \epsilon_{D'} \circ FG(f)$. (You might even think of this as the map $FG(f)$ being "isomorphic" to the map $f$, in some sense.) So that part of the equivalance is like "global isomorphism" from all the objects and arrows spit out by $FG$ to all the original objects and arrows in $\mathcal{D}$. And similarly for the other composition.

Comment: So, my guess is correct? What I'm asking is what pair of functors are to be compared? Considering that $F,G$ go "different ways" I suspected it has to be $GF$ and $\mathrm{id}_\mathcal{C}$ that were to be compared, except I was, and I'm afraid still am, not sure :)

Comment: Ah. Yes, since $GF$ goes from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{C}$, you should compare that to $id_\mathcal{C}$. And $FG$ runs from $\mathcal{D}$ to $\mathcal{D}$, so $FG$ should be compared to $id_\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: Great. It's not easy to describe precisely what you don't understand, hehe ;)

Comment: No problem. Hopefully the answer was still useful to you, even if it wasn't exactly answering your question!